# jQuery plugin columnizer in AngularJS

Tags: jquery-plugins, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm still new with AngularJS directives, now I'm trying to use columnize plugin but without success. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13386804/931340) answer is a good start but won't solve my problem because `Categories.get()` fetches data asynchronously from the server and setting a timeout doesn't seem the solution at all.

```
<div columnize>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in Categories.get()">
            <a ng-href="{{ data.uri }}">{{ data.name }}</a>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="data in data.categories" ng-include="'list.html'"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*Edit:* Categories service.

```
app.factory('Categories',function ($http) {
    var categories = [],
        URL = '/categories';
    if (categories.length == 0) {
        $http.get(URL).success(function (data) {
            categories = data;
        })
    }
    return {
        get: function () {
            return categories;
        },
        ....
    };
```

Based on the source of my data how should make the columnize directive with the columnize jQuery plugin?

Comment: What does `Categories.get()` return? Are you using `ngResource` or is that a custom service?

Comment: Categories is a service living in the $rootscope, it returns an array, not a promise. I dont remeber why ... maybe I couldn't make it work with promises.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to make the columnize directive?