# angularjs: allows only numbers to be typed into a text box

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, numeric

In angularjs is there any functionality available that allows only numbers to be typed into a text box [like](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/)

Comment: use <input ng-pattern="\d*" ... />

Comment: it is for validation.works on submission of form.i want to disallow user enter any other values than number/integer..like this 
http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restrict an input to only accept numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615236/how-do-i-restrict-an-input-to-only-accept-numbers)

Comment: Is there an update to this question that allows for periods, commas as a user types & copy-and-pasting?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This functionality just what you need. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.number

**EDIT:**

You can wrap the jquery plugin into directive. I created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/anazimok/jTJCF/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div>
        <input type="text" min="0" max="99" number-mask="" ng-model="message">
            <button ng-click="handleClick()">Broadcast</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ng-invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JS:

```
// declare a module
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('numberMask', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).numeric();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not quite the OP is asking for. Your solution provides input validation (ie. shows error when non-number is detected) but users can still type non-number in the textbox.

Comment: @AliHasan This shouldn't be the correct answer as it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 65):

This code shows the example how to prevent entering non digit symbols.

```
angular.module('app').
  directive('onlyDigits', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                if (inputValue == undefined) return '';
                var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                if (transformedInput !== inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I simplified the non-digit stripping and wrote a test: https://gist.github.com/henrik/769d49136744ddcaa1dc At the time of writing, the code is JS but the test is CoffeeScript. Soon both will be CoffeeScript, I think.

Comment: double tapping a letter key will make this fail

Comment: as Blowsie notes, this code doesn't work in all cases.. here is a working jsfiddle which I'm trying to update this answer to use: http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/DwKZh/

Comment: The directive should be used with ng-trim=false if you want to explicitly disable input of whitespaces

Comment: The users are able to type whitespaces. Add `attrs.$set('ngTrim', "false");` before parsers for preventing whitespaces.

Answer (score 43):

HTML

```
 <input type="text" name="number" only-digits>
```

// Just type 123

```
  .directive('onlyDigits', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        function inputValue(val) {
          if (val) {
            var digits = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

            if (digits !== val) {
              ctrl.$setViewValue(digits);
              ctrl.$render();
            }
            return parseInt(digits,10);
          }
          return undefined;
        }            
        ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
      }
    };
});
```

// type: 123 or 123.45

```
 .directive('onlyDigits', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        function inputValue(val) {
          if (val) {
            var digits = val.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');

            if (digits.split('.').length > 2) {
              digits = digits.substring(0, digits.length - 1);
            }

            if (digits !== val) {
              ctrl.$setViewValue(digits);
              ctrl.$render();
            }
            return parseFloat(digits);
          }
          return undefined;
        }            
        ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
      }
    };
 });
```

Comment: Your second example (// type: 123 or 123.45) allows multiple decimal places to be entered, e.g. 
    11.22..33.....444 
will return valid.

Comment: I think we can handle that using the following  if (digits.split('.').length > 2)
                        digits = digits.substring(0, digits.length - 1);

Comment: Why the code is so lengthy in angularjs when it is simple in normal javascript for the same requirement??

Comment: How to limit this to 2 digits only?

Comment: @Bharath  for restrict only 2 decimal  -->     if (digits.split('.').length > 1) { digits = digits.substring(0, digits.indexOf('.') + 3); }

Answer (score 37):

I just used ng-keypress in the directive for my input.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-keypress="filterValue($event)"/>
```

JS:

```
$scope.filterValue = function($event){
        if(isNaN(String.fromCharCode($event.keyCode))){
            $event.preventDefault();
        }
};
```

Comment: Whilst this isn't really "the angular way" it seems like a relatively safe option to prevent the user input

Comment: This seems very simple, though the non angular way might stop some, I definitely liked this approach. Had to add 2 other cases which had to be allowed though, event.which === 8 and event.which === 46 (for backspace and delete respectively)

Comment: Nice solution! I used the @Markiv comment to improve your code in a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091218/angularjs-allows-only-numbers-to-be-typed-into-a-text-box#answer-35823435) that allows edition, submit and navigation.

Comment: I liked this solution, and allthough the value is trimmed => I changed the condition a little bit to prevent pressing space bar: if(  isNaN(String.fromCharCode($event.keyCode)) || $event.keyCode === 32)

Comment: Keypress event is deprecated, some of the browsers(namely Chrome) don't support it. Keydown event is also fishy - on some devices, Nexus4, it doesn't report correct key codes.

The only real way to do it (afaik) is to not use characters, but the actual real text.

Answer (score 21):

This is the simplest and fastest way, for allowing the Number input only.

```
<input type="text" id="cardno" placeholder="Enter a Number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' required>
```

Thanks

Comment: if u could put this in a directive it's perfect

Comment: Backspace and delete will not work also -) Need to add additional check

Comment: The question is to allow number input only, if you want more than that , Then of course it can be customised accordingly. So this is just a suggestion , not a concrete answer to all problems.

Comment: I think this is the fates way

Answer (score 7):

To build on Anton's answer a little --

```
angular.module("app").directive("onlyDigits", function ()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope:{
            allowDecimal: '@',
            allowNegative: '@',
            minNum: '@',
            maxNum: '@'
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel)
        {
            if (!ngModel) return;
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (inputValue)
            {
                var decimalFound = false;
                var digits = inputValue.split('').filter(function (s,i)
                {
                    var b = (!isNaN(s) && s != ' ');
                    if (!b && attrs.allowDecimal && attrs.allowDecimal == "true")
                    {
                        if (s == "." && decimalFound == false)
                        {
                            decimalFound = true;
                            b = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!b && attrs.allowNegative && attrs.allowNegative == "true")
                    {
                        b = (s == '-' && i == 0);
                    }

                    return b;
                }).join('');
                if (attrs.maxNum && !isNaN(attrs.maxNum) && parseFloat(digits) > parseFloat(attrs.maxNum))
                {
                    digits = attrs.maxNum;
                }
                if (attrs.minNum && !isNaN(attrs.minNum) && parseFloat(digits) < parseFloat(attrs.minNum))
                {
                    digits = attrs.minNum;
                }
                ngModel.$viewValue = digits;
                ngModel.$render();

                return digits;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Instead of `ngModel.$viewValue = digits` you should use `ngModel.$setViewValue(digits)` so it will hit the rest of ngModelController and ngForm hooks. I needed this since it was a required field and when i entered a letter (which didn't show), the form was marked valid - incorrectly.

Comment: the problem with this directive is if you type legal number and by mistake you type letter your field will removed.

Answer (score 7):

My solution accept Copy&Paste and save the position of the caret. It's used for cost of products so allows positive decimal values only. Can be refactor very easy to allow negative or just integer digits.

```
angular
        .module("client")
        .directive("onlyNumber", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                    element.bind('input', function () {
                        var position = this.selectionStart - 1;

                        //remove all but number and .
                        var fixed = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');  
                        if (fixed.charAt(0) === '.')                  //can't start with .
                            fixed = fixed.slice(1);

                        var pos = fixed.indexOf(".") + 1;
                        if (pos >= 0)               //avoid more than one .
                            fixed = fixed.substr(0, pos) + fixed.slice(pos).replace('.', '');  

                        if (this.value !== fixed) {
                            this.value = fixed;
                            this.selectionStart = position;
                            this.selectionEnd = position;
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

Put on the html page:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" only-number ng-model="vm.cost" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the method that works for me. It's based in [samnau anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091218/angularjs-allows-only-numbers-to-be-typed-into-a-text-box#answer-32148834) but allows to submit the form with `ENTER`, increase and decrease the number with `UP` and `DOWN` arrows, edition with `DEL`,`BACKSPACE`,`LEFT` and `RIGHT`, and navigate trough fields with `TAB`. Note that it works for positive integers such as an amount.

HTML:

```
<input ng-keypress="onlyNumbers($event)" min="0" type="number" step="1" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,8}$/" ng-model="... >
```

ANGULARJS:

```
$scope.onlyNumbers = function(event){   
    var keys={
        'up': 38,'right':39,'down':40,'left':37,
        'escape':27,'backspace':8,'tab':9,'enter':13,'del':46,
        '0':48,'1':49,'2':50,'3':51,'4':52,'5':53,'6':54,'7':55,'8':56,'9':57
    };
    for(var index in keys) {
        if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(index)) continue;
        if (event.charCode==keys[index]||event.keyCode==keys[index]) {
            return; //default event
        }
    }   
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on **djsiz** solution, wrapped in directive.
NOTE: it will not handle digit numbers, but it can be easily updated

```
angular
        .module("app")
        .directive("mwInputRestrict", [
            function () {
                return {
                    restrict: "A",
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                        element.on("keypress", function (event) {
                            if (attrs.mwInputRestrict === "onlynumbers") {
                                // allow only digits to be entered, or backspace and delete keys to be pressed
                                return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) ||
                                       (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46);
                            }
                            return true;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
```

HTML

```
 <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="inputHeight"
        name="inputHeight"
        placeholder="Height"
        mw-input-restrict="onlynumbers"
        ng-model="ctbtVm.dto.height">
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use HTML5

```
<input type="number" min="0"/>
```

Comment: Yes, *type="number"* will definitely work great. But it fails to render properly when we this kind of input with bootstrap input groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can check 
https://github.com/rajesh38/ng-only-number

1. It restricts input to only numbers and decimal point in a textbox while typing.
2. You can limit the number of digits to be allowed before and after the decimal point
3. It also trims the digits after the decimal point if the decimal point is removed from the textbox e.g. if you have put 123.45 and then remove the decimal point it will also remove the trailing digits after the decimal point and make it 123.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:
Use **ng-pattern** with the RegExp "**/^[0-9]+$/**" that means only integer numbers are valid.

```
<form novalidate name="form">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="age" id="age" name="age" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/">
    <span ng-show="form.age.$error.pattern">The value is not a valid integer</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution will accept only numeric, '.' and '-'

Also this restricts the space entry on text box. I had used the directive to achieve the same.

Please have the solution on below working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/vfsHX/2697/

HTML:

```
<form ng-app="myapp" name="myform" novalidate> 
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<input name="number" is-number ng-model="wks.number">
<span ng-show="!wks.validity">Value is invalid</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.wks =  {number: 1, validity: true}
});

app.directive('isNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {   
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
          if(event.which === 32) {
            event.returnValue = false;
            return false;
          }
       }); 
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue,oldValue) {
                var arr = String(newValue).split("");
                if (arr.length === 0) return;
                if (arr.length === 1 && (arr[0] == '-' || arr[0] === '.' )) return;
                if (arr.length === 2 && newValue === '-.') return;
                if (isNaN(newValue)) {
                    //scope.wks.number = oldValue;
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(oldValue);
                                    ngModel.$render();
                }
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple and understandable.
Just copy paste this code and your issue will get resolved.For more conditions just change the value in pattern.and your work will done.

```
<input type="text"  pattern="[0-9]{0,}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter only numeric value. Special character are not allowed.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer serves as a simplification and optimisation over [Leopoldo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35823435/3594067).

Trigger a function from your input on every keydown like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-keydown="onlyNumbers($event);"/>
```

You can describe the function in this manner in your controller

```
$scope.onlyNumbers = function(event){    
    // 'up': 38,'right':39,'down':40,'left':37,
    // 'escape':27,'backspace':8,'tab':9,'enter':13,'del':46,
    // '0':48,'1':49,'2':50,'3':51,'4':52,'5':53,'6':54,'7':55,'8':56,'9':57
    var keys = { 38:true,39:true,40:true,37:true,27:true,8:true,9:true,13:true,
                 46:true,48:true,49:true, 50:true,51:true,52:true,53:true,
                 54:true,55:true,56:true,57:true };

    // if the pressed key is not listed, do not perform any action
    if(!keys[event.keyCode]) { event.preventDefault(); }
}
```

In case you're using Angular 2+, you can call this same function in this manner:

```
<input type="text" (keydown)="onlyNumbers($event);"/>
```

Your Angular 2+ function should look something like this:

```
onlyNumbers(event) { // the logic here }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="phone" numbers-only >
```

You can use this way if you want only numbers :)

here is the the demo [click](https://codepen.io/apuchkov/pen/ILjFr)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and ended up hooking and event

```
ng-change="changeCount()"
```

then:

```
self.changeCount = function () {
      if (!self.info.itemcount) {
        self.info.itemcount = 1;
      }
 };
```

So the user is defaulted to 1 if a invalid number is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I arraged the jQuery in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

```
.directive('numbersCommaOnly', function(){
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        element.on('keydown', function(event) {                  
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
            var array2 = [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]
            if (array2.indexOf(event.which) !== -1 ||
                 // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (event.which == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                 // Allow: Ctrl+C
                (event.which == 67 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                 // Allow: Ctrl+X
                (event.which == 88 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                 // Allow: home, end, left, right
                (event.which >= 35 && event.which <= 39)) {
                     // let it happen, don't do anything
                     return;
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((event.shiftKey || (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) && (event.which < 96 || event.which > 105)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
         });

     }
   };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="text" ng-keypress="checkNumeric($event)"/>
 //inside controller
 $scope.dot = false
 $scope.checkNumeric = function($event){
 if(String.fromCharCode($event.keyCode) == "." && !$scope.dot){
    $scope.dot = true
 }
 else if( isNaN(String.fromCharCode($event.keyCode))){
   $event.preventDefault();
 }
```

Comment: to allow float value!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but this adaptation of **My Mai**'s answer works nicely for me...

```
angular.module("app").directive("numbersOnly", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        function inputValue(val) {
            if (val) {
                //transform val to a string so replace works
                var myVal = val.toString();

                //replace any non numeric characters with nothing
                var digits = myVal.replace(/\D/g, "");

                //if anything needs replacing - do it!
                if (digits !== myVal) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(digits);
                    ctrl.$render();
                }
                return parseFloat(digits);
            }
            return undefined;
        }
        ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done at

.js

```
$scope.numberOnly="(^[0-9]+$)";
```

.html

```
<input type="text" name="rollNo" ng-model="stud.rollNo" ng-pattern="numberOnly" ng-maxlength="10" maxlength="10" md-maxlength="10" ng-required="true" >
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `ng-only-number` to allow only numbers, for example:

```
<input type="text" ng-only-number data-max-length=5>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 <input
    onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) ||                         
    event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 46">
```

Comment: Great that you answered, and while this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks @Fraser . If you do not mind Can you help me for right ans please :)