# Angular directive: Validate value before binding it to model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to not bind value to model , and ONLY  bind it to model when value is valid.

Comment: you could use `$validator` on `ngModel` from directive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$parsers`. The example below restricts input to your model for numbers only. Obviously you can change that to be whatever you require to make your input valid.

```
angular.module('app').
directive('onlyDigits', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                if (inputValue == undefined) return '';
                var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                if (transformedInput !== inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
});

<input type="text" name="number" only-digits>
```

[Code sample comes from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091218/angularjs-allows-only-numbers-to-be-typed-into-a-text-box)