# Text Input allow only Integer input in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-validation

I want to set the html input[number] `<input type="number" />` to allow **only integer** input (not float).

Basically, the html input[number] allow '.' to be entered for float input and I don't want that.

Is there a quick way to accomplish it in AngularJS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs: allows only numbers to be typed into a text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091218/angularjs-allows-only-numbers-to-be-typed-into-a-text-box)

Comment: Note that the question is asking about _integers_, not _numbers_.

Answer (score 21):

Here is how this can be achieved.

1. With input type - 'text'

   **Directive:**

   ```
   app.directive('onlyNumbers', function () {
       return  {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
               elm.on('keydown', function (event) {
                   if(event.shiftKey){event.preventDefault(); return false;}
                   //console.log(event.which);
                   if ([8, 13, 27, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(event.which) > -1) {
                       // backspace, enter, escape, arrows
                       return true;
                   } else if (event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) {
                       // numbers 0 to 9
                       return true;
                   } else if (event.which >= 96 && event.which <= 105) {
                       // numpad number
                       return true;
                   } 
                   // else if ([110, 190].indexOf(event.which) > -1) {
                   //     // dot and numpad dot
                   //     return true;
                   // }
                   else {
                       event.preventDefault();
                       return false;
                   }
               });
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   **HTML:**

   ```
   <input type="text" only-numbers>
   ```
2. With input type - 'number'

   **Directive:**

   ```
   app.directive('noFloat', function () {
   return  {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
           elm.on('keydown', function (event) {
             if ([110, 190].indexOf(event.which) > -1) {
                   // dot and numpad dot
                   event.preventDefault();
                   return false;
               }
               else{
                 return true;
               }
           });
       }
   }
   });
   ```

   **HTML:** 
   `<input type="number" step="1" no-float>`

Check out the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lT814woGPN4FB1CjBtfg?p=preview)

Comment: Tanx buddy, I appreciate that

Answer (score 3):

Use pattern property:

`<input type="number" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" required>`

please see the demo : https://jsfiddle.net/JBalu/vfbgrd5n/

may help.

Comment: '5.' and '5,' shouldn't be valid.

Answer (score 2):

Please find the fiddle
 http://jsfiddle.net/8a4sg0mo/

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('numbersOnly', function(){
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
       modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

       if (inputValue == undefined) return '' 
       var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
       if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
          modelCtrl.$render();
       }         

       return transformedInput;         
   });
 }
   };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.number = ''
}
```

It will allow only numbers to be entered, purely done using angular js.

Comment: Yeah the code is work. Unfortunately, if I use it inside my directive, I'll get an error "inputValue.replace is not a function". Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

**Full working Sample:Custom Directive**
The below works just fine

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

  <input type="text" allow-numbers-only />

  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.title = "App"
    })



    app.directive("allowNumbersOnly", function() {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind("keydown", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 8) {
              return false;
            } else if (!(event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58) || event.shiftKey) {
              event.preventDefault();
              return false;
            }
          });



        }
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have looked for this many times, I had used directives in previous projects, but have finally founded a way that angular js provides by itself and hence can get rid of **directives**. Take a look at this code given at this link [angularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)

The code shown there is as follows :

```
<script>
  angular.module('numberExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.example = {
        value: 12
      };
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Number:
    <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
           min="0" max="99" required>
 </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
      Required!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.number">
      Not valid number!</span>
  </div>
  <tt>value = {{example.value}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function () {
    angular
    .module('urModule').directive('numbersOnly', numbersOnly);
    function numbersOnly() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
                function fromUser(text) {
                    if (text) {
                        var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                        if (transformedInput !== text) {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                            ngModelCtrl.$render();
                        }
                        return transformedInput;
                    }
                    return undefined;
                }
                ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more information. References etc

Answer (score -3):

`input[type=number]` by definition only accepts integers as input. Try it out yourself. Try typing in letters and it won't allow you.

There's no need for JavaScript as it's already built in. Did you perhaps mean `input[type=text]`?

You can accomplish that via angular directives. It would look something like this (not sure about my syntax though)

```
app.directive('onlyNumbers', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("keydown", function(event) {
                if ((event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode < 58) && !event.shiftKey) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The syntax might have a few errors, but I will break down the basic formula.

Since we are working with an input element, it makes sense that we use an `attribute` directive. We can do this, by setting the `restrict` property to A.

Since we will be listening for keypress events, we should use the `link` function. We want to listen for the `keydown` event, to detect when a key is starting to be pressed.

To find if the user typed a number, we will use `keyCodes`, for which the number keys are 48 through 57 representing 0 through 9 respectively. However, we didn't account for special characters, which require hitting the number keys. So we make sure the shift key isn't being pressed either.

Then we can add this directive as an attribute on our input element.

```
<input type="text" only-numbers />
```

Comment: `input[type=number]` would not work as it allows '.' to be entered. The OP doesn't want float values to be entered