# AngularJS prevent number input to add decimal values

Tags: angularjs, validation, design-patterns, input, numbers

I have the following input of type number:

```
<input class="number text-center" type="number" step="1"
       ng-model="item.formattedQuantity"
       ng-disabled="item.discount === '100.00'"
       ng-change="change(item)"
       ng-blur="blur(item)" min="0" />
```

What can I do to forbid users adding decimal values? I tried adding `step=0.01` and `ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/"` but users could still place values like `1.5`, `31.56`, etc.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013311/text-input-allow-only-integer-input-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a directive to achieve that.

```
app.directive('numericInput', function () {
    return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            elm.on('input', function (event) {
                var regex = RegExp('^[0-9]+$');
                if(regex.test(event.target.value)){
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                    return true;
                else {
                    event.preventDefault(); return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Or you can try the angularjs style ([found codepen here](https://codepen.io/apuchkov/pen/ILjFr))

```
app.directive('numericInput', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                if (text) {
                    var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                    if (transformedInput !== text) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                }
                return undefined;
            }            
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
});
```

Then in your html

```
<input numeric-input class="number text-center" type="number" step="1"
       ng-model="item.formattedQuantity"
       ng-disabled="item.discount === '100.00'"
       ng-change="change(item)" ng-blur="blur(item)" min="0" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can still add values like 1.5, etc

Comment: You can try the ng-model approach from angular. I edited the answer.