# allow only numeric value to enter in the input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have written the below directive which allow only numeric value to be entered in the input field.The same is working fine except allowing alphanumeric also to be entered for example if i have copied "abc123" and pasting the same in input field then it is accepting numeric and ignoring alphabet which should not be the case .In this case it should not allow anything to be paste in the input field. Please help.

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl){
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
            if (inputValue === undefined) return '';

            var cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace('.', '')
                .replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')
                .replace(/\./, "x")
                .replace(/\./g, "")
                .replace(/x/, ".");
            if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
                modelCtrl.$render();
            }
            return cleanInputValue;
        })
    }
```

Comment: Check [angularjs: allows only numbers to be typed into a text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091218/angularjs-allows-only-numbers-to-be-typed-into-a-text-box).

Comment: If you want to cancel the `paste` completely then you'd have to monitor the clipboard. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser

Answer (score 1):

#### `$parsers`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test" format="number" />
```

*JS*

```
app.directive('format', ['$filter', '$window', function($filter, $window) {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) return;

      scope.vKey = 86;
      scope.ctrlVDown = false;
      angular.element($window).bind("keydown", function($event) {
        console.log($event.keyCode);
        if ($event.keyCode == scope.vKey) {
          scope.ctrlVDown = true;
        } else {
          scope.ctrlVDown = false;
        }
      });


      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');

        console.log(scope.ctrlVDown);

        if (scope.ctrlVDown && plainNumber.length !== viewValue.length) {
          elem.val('');
          return '';
        } else {
          elem.val(plainNumber);
          return plainNumber;
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wct9bzrz/)

Comment: Still i am facing the same problem.If you will copy a alphanumeric value and paste it then it will paste the number and ignore alphabet.

Comment: @Raj I tried demo 1, I copied `aaaa232323sds` and got `232323`.

Comment: That is what not required.I want to ignore all the value if it is alphanumeric(e.g  if aaaa232323sds is pasted then nothing should be pasted).Allow to paste value in input field if it is only number

Comment: @Raj well, you cannot achieve that. Check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/2s9bdk67/    it will work for u but if user types inside input field numeric + alpha chars it will also clear the form

Comment: Thanks Maxim !! But i am able to type alphabet if typed two times and if you will copy "avcds565456" and paste the same two times then in second time it is accepting the entire value.

Comment: @Raj I think you can do your homework :). Play with flags

Comment: Thanks for the help Maxim !!

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple directive, which allows you only to enter numbers inside a input field.

When linked to an input field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test" valid-number>
```

It bind a `keydown` event on the input field, which checks what key has been pressed. Each key on your keyboard has an global number. For example: <kbd>enter</kbd> has the numer *13* assigned.

[A complete list of key codes](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

When you press a key on your keyboard, and its matches the key code listed inside `var keyCode`

```
var keyCode = [8, 9, 37, 39, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 110];
```

then we prevent the action from executing.

```js
(function () {

  angular.module("app", [])
  
  .directive("validNumber", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            require: "?ngModel",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                if (!ngModel) return;
                var keyCode = [8, 9, 37, 39, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 110];
                element.bind("keydown", function (event) {
                    if ($.inArray(event.which, keyCode) === -1) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.$eval(attrs.validNumber);
                            event.preventDefault();
                        });
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <input type="text" ng-model="test" valid-number="" name="test">
</div>
```

---

### UPDATE

---

Based on your comments on other posted awnsers. You can just use `.replace()` function to replace everything except numbers.

Even when you copy and paste a valid number with invalid characters, it will replace the invalid characters.

I allowed users to write an dot `.`, because `5.2` is a valid number. But if you dont want this, you can replace the `regex` with

```
value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
```

**DEMO**

```js
(function () {

  angular.module("app", [])
  
  .directive("validNumber", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            require: "?ngModel",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                if (!ngModel) return;

                element.bind("keypress keyup", function (event) {
                    var value = element.val();
                    value = value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
                    
                    element.val(value);
                });
            }
        };
    });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <input type="text" ng-model="test" valid-number="" name="test">
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain what this key code array is doing?Can you see my code and help me to change the regex to make it work. I think we can we do this by using proper regex.

Comment: Replace `inputValue.replace('.', '')
                .replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')
                .replace(/\./, "x")
                .replace(/\./g, "")
                .replace(/x/, ".");` to `inputValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");`

Comment: This will behave like it was behaving earlier.It will accept number and ignore alphabet if we will paste any alphanumeric value.

Comment: Also this will not allow to paste numeric value.This is valid only if typing with key

Comment: `Also this will not allow to paste numeric value.This is valid only if typing with key`. Tested and does work. I can paste a numeric value inside it. What  browser did you test on?

Comment: copy "abc213wse" and paste that in the input field.It will accept the number i.e 213 will pasted and rest will be ignored.I this case nothing should be pasted.

Comment: I am looking for a regex for alphanumeric value for example :"as12ws".So let say we pasted as "12sas1" so regex will check if the entire value consist of aything other number if so then it will replace the value with empty string

Comment: I have created a regex i.e var cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace('.', '')
     .replace(/^(?:[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]|[a-zA-Z]+[.,!@#$]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[.,!@#$]+[a-zA-Z])[a-z0-9#$@!]*$/g, '')
     .replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This may helpful

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button 
{   
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* some part are still there even though it is hidden */
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <input type="number" >
</div>
```

if you feel uncomfortable with key 'e' use the following one

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.myFunc = function (event) {    
    if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};
});
```

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button 
{   
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* some part are still there even though it is hidden */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-keypress="myFunc($event)">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks !! I have already tried this . But in this case it is accepting "e" also which should not be the case.

Comment: @Raj. I have made changes as per your requirement

Comment: Thanks for your effort! But this is not working in case of copy paste.If you will copy and paste some alphanumeric value then it is accepting that which should not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set your input type to *number*?

```
<input type="number" />
```

This will automatically strip all alphabetical characters even when user will use paste

Comment: In this case number icon will be shown on the UI which i dont want.thanks