# how to format numbers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there any way to format numbers in Angular ?

I have this

```
applyIfRisk = function(slip) {
  _.assign(slip, {
    risk: slip.risk,
    win: Math.ceil(slip.risk * 1.67)
  });
}, applyIfWin = function(slip) {
  _.assign(slip, {
    risk: Math.ceil(slip.win * 1.11),
    win: slip.win
  });
}
```

which is attach to this html

```
<input ng-model="slip.win"
       ng-change="riskWinCalculations(slip, 'WINIFBET')"> 

<input ng-model="slip.risk"
       ng-change="riskWinCalculations(slip, 'RISKIFBET')">
```

but it is returning... let's say: `100000`, and I need: `100,000`

someone told me to use `{{slip.win | number}}` but I am not able to use it because this is a model, not an expression.

what should I do here ?

**UPDATE**

some post that my question is a duplicate of another which is not, the question is almost the same, but the answers doesn't help me.

Comment: could you provide an example plunker ? your input is not very clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS number input formatted view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001895/angularjs-number-input-formatted-view)

Comment: @Blackhole hey ? what are you doing ? the answers in that post are not about the same I am asking here. Look at it, Yizus.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer, first, no need for snidy remarks in comments... Second, you have to clarify if you expect a behavior of a mask (automatically format) or only on focus...

Comment: @NewDev all I am doing is working with that model, when the model is updated in the view it returns numbers like: 111000, and I need 111,000 that's it. Someone told me to use the filter ```| number``` but I can't because it is a model. And what is 'snidy' ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer, so, in fact, the linked question (with its demo example) should help you

Answer (score 0):

Use the number filter, here is a link to the angular documentation: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Comment: And?... did you actually read the question there and the most upvoted answer?