# Restrict input type number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-material

I'm having trouble to restrict an input type number to positive number only. As stated in that post : [HTML5: number input type that takes only integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers) I am **not** looking for the step="1" answer since it allows the user to type {e.,} as well.

I am using a directive I found on a related post ([How do I restrict an input to only accept numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615236/how-do-i-restrict-an-input-to-only-accept-numbers)) to which I just added a few console log and a toString() :

It's working fine when the input type is a text, however it's never called when the input type is number and I type either 'e' ',' or '.'.

Any idea on what I am missing here ? I want to use the input type=number to enable the arrow to select a value using angular material.

```js
function restrictInput($mdDialog) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      function inputValue(value) {
        console.log("hello ! :", value)
        var val = value.toString();
        console.log("goodbye ! : ", val)
        if (val) {
          var digits = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
          console.log("digits :", digits)
          console.log("val : ", val)
          if (digits !== val) {
            ctrl.$setViewValue(digits);
            ctrl.$render();
          }
          return parseInt(digits, 10);
        }
        return undefined;
      }
      ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
    }
  };
}
```

Html is something like this :

```html
<md-input-container flex class="md-input-has-placeholder">
  <label>Années d'expérience stage inclus</label>
    <input
      type="number"
      required
      step="1"
      restrict-input
      min="0"
      name="Expérience stage"
      ng-model="model">
    <div ng-messages="form['Expérience stage'].$error" md-auto-hide="false">
      <div ng-message="required">Requis</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

**EDIT**

Using getter setter (ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }") worked out perfectly here.

Comment: write a watch for $scope.model and restrict the input and replace it there

Comment: `<input type="number" min="0">` is a start for numeric values. Then you just have to check it's not a letter. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372067/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-input-type-number-getting-negative-values

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use directive if just need to restrict input type "number" to accept only integer.

```
<input type="number" ng-pattern="/^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/" >
```

Can you type above code in your app?

This will only accept numbers.

Comment: Simpler pattern would be `/^[0-9]+$/`

Comment: It is working for me. You can see demo here first input is of answer pattern

-- http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/63mwL/