# Allow only characters in textbox using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just want to validate textbox in my project in such a way so that a user could not enter any value other than characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554915/angular-directive-ignore-non-numeric-input

Answer (score 2):

**Hackish? way**, $watch the ng-model in your controller:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myText">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.$watch('myText', function() {
   // put logic to strip out all non-character characters here
   if ($scope.myText  ... regex to look for ... ) {
      // strip out the non-characters
   }
})
```

**Best way**, use a $parser in a directive.
I'm not going to repeat the already good answer provided by @pkozlowski.opensource, so here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14425022/215945

Don't try to use ng-change -- it will cause problems.  See [AngularJS - reset of $scope.value doesn't change value in template (random behavior)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176925/angularjs-reset-of-scope-value-doesnt-change-value-in-template-random-behav)

**Update:**
[ng-pattern](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.text) can also be used to define a regex that will limit what is allowed in the field.  See also the ["cookbook" page about forms](http://docs.angularjs.org/cookbook/form).

Comment: It seems u didn't understand my problem. I want that user could not enter any value other than character in the textbox. So i think here we have to use onkeypress function. Wht u say??

Comment: I believe the two solutions I provided should work.  I just updated my answer with information about ng-pattern.  If you can't get it to work using one of these three solutions, please post a [fiddle](http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/) or a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/) of what you tried.

Comment: I already use ng-pattern for this purpose & it served me well for validating purpose but actually now i want that user couldn't even type anything in textbox apart from characters. Could you please help me with this??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15556249/215945 where a directive was written to prevent non-numeric characters from being entered.  Just change the regex in the directive to allow only characters.