# Accepting only integers and floating point numbers in angular js on each key stroke

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, dom-events, javascript-framework

How can angular js monitor key strokes in such a way that the input field in html does not accept non numerical values and accept only integers and floating point numbers on each key stroke?

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input ng-pattern="/^(?=.+)(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$/" ng-model="value" name="number"/>
  Valid? {{myForm.number.$valid}}
</form>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you've provided? You may be looking for something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15556249/1266600

Comment: The link to the solution you posted works fine for accepting integer only values but it does not accept floating point values for e.g. 3.14

Comment: You need to modify it to fit your pattern.

Comment: See this man : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20368741/2837412

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking about correct **"float/integers" regex** pattern then try this one :

```
/^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

An ideal idea for decimal numbers and setting the decimal region to 2

```
    ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"
```