# Only allow numbers and comma

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation

This current function prevents the user from typing any character but numbers. I would like to adjust it to allow commas and the spacebar as well. How would I adjust it.

```
numbersFunction(event: any): boolean {
    const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: 'Comma' KeyCode is 188, if that helps...

Comment: ... What's the specific issue? I mean... the char codes are documented and you know the condition.

Comment: @DaveNewton I was looking [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) and it threw me off. Probably a bad reference

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to restrict to floating numbers only, you could use the [Validators.pattern](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern) to enforce the correct pattern.

There is example of patterns in other questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987081/accepting-only-integers-and-floating-point-numbers-in-angular-js-on-each-key-str).