# Angular text form with numbers only?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, text, input

So I have an input form in Angular here:

```
<input ng-model="sc.zip" class="form-control" maxlength="5" type="text" />
```

I don't want type="numbers" because the form needs to be a plain empty textbox. However, I only want the user to be able to type numbers. Either I need to detect when the input is not a digit, or be able to search through the box to find non-digits when submitting.

Either way, I need to validate that the form is digits only. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular directive ignore non-numeric input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554915/angular-directive-ignore-non-numeric-input)

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs: allows only numbers to be typed into a text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091218/angularjs-allows-only-numbers-to-be-typed-into-a-text-box)

Answer (score 1):

use regex

```
  <input name="title" type="text" ng-model="sc.zip" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" required/>
```